# Stack on Setting Paypal Discount promo

Tags: paypal, set, discount

Stack on Setting Paypal Discount promo

Hi would like to set promo discount for my Paypal subscription but i ended and stack solving how i can set the Trial period (total cycles and Remaining cycles)

I setted up my button with this snippets

```
<!-- First two Days of subscription are free. -->
 <input type="hidden" name="a1"value="10">
 <input type="hidden"name="p1" value="2">
 <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="D">

<!-- Recurring subscription payments. -->
 <input type="hidden" name="a1"value="20">
 <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D">
 <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
```

and paypal sumarises it as

"$10 USD for the first 2 Days then $20 for each day"

But what i wanted to state is
   "$10 USD each day for the first 2 Days then $20 for each day"

Answer (score 0):

**Either you can state 20 USD for 2 days like below :**

```
<!-- First two Days of subscription are free. -->
 <input type="hidden" name="a1"value="20">
 <input type="hidden"name="p1" value="2">
 <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="D">
```

**Or you can set the two trial period for 10 USD each days like below**

```
<!-- First two Days of subscription are free. -->
 <input type="hidden" name="a1"value="10">
 <input type="hidden"name="p1" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="D">

  <input type="hidden" name="a2"value="10">
 <input type="hidden"name="p2" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="t2" value="D">
```

For this PayPal will show something like :

**$10.00 USD for the first day
Then $10.00 USD for the next day
Then $20.00 USD for each day**

Comment: hi eshan how about if i turn the trial into 3 days? p1 with the value of 3?
i think you just added the second trial period

Comment: If you want to offer trial period for 3 days for 30 USD then you can set a1=30 , p1=3 .